# Does Kubernetes support auto-scaling now?

Tags: kubernetes

Can Kubernetes automatically add or reduce the number of pods，when it monitors for increases or decreases in load (i.e. CPU load, traffic)?

If it's possible, how can I configure it?

Comment: Yes.  See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749774/kubernetes-autoscaling-containers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes Autoscaling Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749774/kubernetes-autoscaling-containers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto scaling of pods is not yet available, but it's definitely on our roadmap, as mentioned by Brendan in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26914911/1925481).

It could actually be easily built outside of the core of Kubernetes, using the public Kubernetes API. If you'd rather wait for someone else to build it, though, it looks like a contributor has [started planning a design for one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/autoscaling.md).

Comment: Kubernetes 1.3 added support. For details, see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428953/783510

Answer (score 0):

Yes Kubernetes support auto-scaling of pods base on limit set i.e. CPU or Memory 
       imagePullPolicy: Always
        **resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "256m"
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "60m"**

kubectl autoscale deployment nginx --cpu-percent=80 --min=5 --max=10 
To view 
kubectl get hpa

NAME      REFERENCE           TARGETS    MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
nginx    Deployment/nginx   0% / 50%   5         10        5          1d

Answer (score 0):

Yes,new versions of kubernetes support auto-scaling.It was added to K8 as horizontal pod scaling.Find out more on 
    https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

In order to use auto-scaling

```
kubectl autoscale deployment deployment_name --cpu-percent=10 --min=2 --max=5
```

> --cpu-percent to denote the limit up to which scaling will not be performed .
>   --min denote minimum number of pods.
>   --max denote maximum number of pods.

run

```
kubectl get hpa
```

observe the result .
TARGETS column shows the current-cpu%/cpu-percent-mentioned-during-autoscale  For this scenario it is 10 .
Kubernetes automatically create new pods as load increases. 
to check this go to this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/
.
after running busybox execute

```
kubectl get pods
```

to check the no of pods.